# Java instance variable life cycle

Tags: java, lifecycle

I want to understand more about the Java instance variable life cycle. Consider below scenario:

```
public class A {

    B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void process() {
        C c = getC();
        b.register(c.getD());
    }

    private C getC() {
        return new C(new D());
    }
}

public class B {
    List<D> dList;

    public B() {
        dList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void register(D d) {
        dList.add(d);
    }
}

public class C {
    D d;

    public C(D d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public D getD() {
        return this.d;
    }
}
```

When the public method `process` of an A object is called, a local variable C is created. The life cycle of c should end once this method returns. However, the c's instance variable D is now referenced by b so it shouldn't be garbage collected even when the `process` method returns. Is it possible for an object being eligible for GC but not its instance variable? How does the life cycle works for c and its instance variable d?

It would be nice if you can recommend some docs on this topic. I believe I understand basic concepts but definitely need to dive deeper.

Comment: It's certainly possible for an object to be eligible for GC and not its instance variable.  It's outright common.  You've demonstrated it here.  GC collects any object which there aren't any remaining references to.  The `D` is referenced; the `C` isn't; the `C` gets collected.

Comment: Instance variables aren't garbage collected. The object referenced by an instance variable will be GC'd when the object can no longer to reached by any code. Same for the object that has the instance variable. You need to make a more clear separation in your head between *variables* and *object instances*. A variable can *reference* an object instance, but it is not the instance, just a reference to it. An object instance can have instance variables, also called *fields*, but variables and object instances are two entirely different things. With this in mind, try asking the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very big difference between an object and a variable.

Java is *all* pointers, except for primitives. Except, pointers is a somewhat dirty word, so in java these are called references. Potayto - potahto, though.

So, in this:

```
C c = getC();
```

That's just syntax sugar for:

```
C c;
c = getC();
```

The `c` variable is **a pointer** (a reference). It's like a little piece of paper with a treasure map on it. **It is not the treasure**.

getC will end up running: `new C(new D())`.

`new` is java-ese for: Conjure up treasure from thin air, bury it, and return me a treasure map that points at it. so, `new D()` will make treasure, bury it in the sand, and then give you a treasure map (not the treasure). Then, the treasure map is passed to C. And now 'java is all pass-by-value, i.e. only copies are passed' starts making sense: There is only one 'D' treasure. But that map? That's copied. Maps are cheap, small, and copied all the time.

Thus, C's constructor is run with a copy of the map to that new D treasure you made, resulting in a C treasure having been created, and buried, and now your C variable is a treasure map which, if you follow it, would get you to that treasure.

When your method ends, that treasure map poofs into thin air instantaneously. That treasure, though? That sticks around. For a while.

Any treasure buried in the sands where nobody has a treasure map to it anymore? That will be garbage collected eventually.

To elaborate on this way of thinking about it, `.` is java-ese for: Follow and dig. `foo.bar()` means: Take the treasure map named `foo`, and follow the map to the big X on it, then, dig down and open the treasure, and then yell 'hey, I send you the message "bar"' at it, which will make the treasure do something interesting, presumably.

Trying to follow a blank treasure map results in a NullPointerException.